# pivot table in excel using UIpath

Tags: excel, pivot, uipath

Hi I am planning to make a pivot table using UIpath.

Is there a way to make a pivot using UIpath? anyone have experienced on this?
what function to use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about what you are trying to do?

I'd suggest you are going to have to create an empty Excel workbook first and then  add a VBA macro to it that will create a pivot table.

You can then use UIPath to pull in the raw data into the workbook and execute the macro to actually create the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of doing in

1. Macro. Record macro and use "Execute macro" activity in the uipath program
2. UI Automation

select the data to make pivot using 'select range' activity.
using send hotkey, pass Alt+NVT (Will open the pivot dialog box)
select the row,column etc using find element or find image and drag and drop to required fields (Drag and drop can be done by using a combination of'click up' and 'click down' property in click activity

Answer (score 0):

3 ways
1)Macro
2)Ui Automation
3)Launch the excel using uipath and use send hotkeys to trigger excel shortcuts for Pivot Table Creation